# Using ConnectionFactory and retrieve the data from url

Tags: blackberry

```
public class ConsumeFactoryThread extends Thread {
    private String url;

    public ConsumeFactoryThread(String url){

        this.url = url;

    }


    public void run(){

        ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
        ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;

        connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);

        if(connDesc != null)
        {

            HttpConnection httpConn;
            httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();

            try
            {
                final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        //data retrieved



                    }

                });
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I got the above code from one of Blackberry's articles, but I'm not entirely sure as to how I get the raw String of the contents of the url, which in my case is going to be a json string.

I know when I was not using ConnectionFactory I used an inputstream to get the data, but I don't know if it is the same with the newer api.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking to do is the following:

```
is = ((Connection) httpConn).openInputStream();
byte[] data = net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
String result = new String(data);
```

This will grab the input stream the HttpConnection object has gathered, use the RIM IOUtils class to nicely put it into an array then finally create a String from the data. It should be possible from their to use the JSON libraries that RIM include in their SDK to work on the JSON.

Note: Not sure if the cast is required, btw this is untested code.

You should also note there are 3 different APIs which you can use to create a network connection on BlackBerry.

**Using the Generic Connection Framework**

The oldest methed (OS 5 below) is a basic J2ME implementation with additional transport descriptors appended to the end of the URL. It uses the J2ME GCF. A great explanation is given [here](http://www.localytics.com/blog/2009/how-to-reliably-establish-a-network-connection-on-any-blackberry-device/), describing how to always reliably open a HTTPConnection.

**Using the Network API**

Introduced in OS 5 and above. This is the current method you are using. It wraps over the nasty descriptor Strings that are added to the end of the URL in the GCF through the use of the ConnectionFactory and ConnectionDescriptor classes.

**Using the Communications API**

Introduced into [OS 6](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Web_services_1251782_11.jsp) and above. This is the newest possible method, it is an even higher abstraction on the Network API. These API's abstract how the actual data is gathered and try to not bother you with the details of the protocol. The useful thing about this API is you just get the resulting data and don't have to worry about the implementation details.

You should note that as you are working with JSON it even will wrap around the details of converting the resulting data and convert it into the format you wanted. An example is shown [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Parsing_a_JSON_data_structure_1226148_11.jsp).